# Angular 6 Interceptor: request again after got new token

Tags: angular, angular6, interceptor

following problem with my interceptor in Angular 7:
When I get 401 (unauthorized) from my backend api, refreshing token is success but the request isn't done again. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            catchError((error: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    this.oauthService = this.injector.get(OAuthService);
                    this.oauthService.silentRefresh().then(() => {
                        return next.handle(request);
                    }).catch(() => this.oauthService.logOut());
                }
                return of(error);
            }) as any
        );
}
```

Comment: you can't return from `then`

Comment: why are you using `as any` after the `catchError(...)` block?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an observable from the then block. You don't subscribe to that, which is why the HttpRequest is not done. Use `fromPromise`, pipe that into catch and return the fromPromise call instead of `of(error)`.

Comment: Do you have an example for this? angular 6 uses rxjs v6 so i have to work with `from` instead of `fromPromise`